# Advice on CSS positioning whilst removing and adding elements

Tags: css, positioning

I have 3 inputs and an image (relating to x y and z measurements). They are all positioned fairly spontaneously so I am using left and top px values to get them exact. So far I have used relative positioning.

My issue is when I change a checkbox I hide the z input and change the image. When I do this everything shifts about in a horrible way. Also there is plenty of white space at the bottom of the page which may be down to using a negative top value for the image.

Should I be using absolute positioning or something else altogether?

Thanks,

Rick

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/WY2DX/52/ (Using SCSS may be CSS issues :s)

Comment: Can you put code on jsfiddle.net that shows the problem you are encountering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presuming you need to be adding and removing elements, you should probably not be using relative positioning. Relative means that the element is not removed from the DOM with regard to positioning, so the size and position of one element will effect the next.

[Learn CSS Positioning in Ten Steps](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/) is a **great** tutorial which gives you a run down of the different positioning methods. I believe what you are looking for would be **step 4**, `position:relative` for a parent container, then `position:absolute` for your x, y, and z labels.

**EDIT:**

I'm not totally clear on how your example is supposed to work, but I am wondering if the labels are truly meant to be positioned spontaneously or if the image is? You may also want to consider letting the labels be positioned normally, and using `position:absolute` for the image?

http://jsfiddle.net/vh5pY/3/

Answer (score 1):

Could you proved a basic markup/css setup of what you are using?

But yes, it seems both your issues are caused by using [position: relative;] as it positions an element relative to its original position.  Meaning if element 'A' was originally present at 0, 0 (X,Y) and you do { position: relative; left: 120px;, top: 120px; }, element 'A' will re-position to 120, 120 (X,Y), but it still takes up 'physical space' at 0,0 (X,Y).  With that, when you're hiding or removing one of the elements, that 'physical space' is no longer being used and the rest of the content will shift to accommodate for the change.

You may use absolute positioning to avoid this, but it may also depend on the context of the use.

Answer (score 1):

Use relative positioning on the parent container and absolute positioning for each child item. That way adding or removing a child element will not affect any of its siblings.